# One table relationship with two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, erd

There is an attribute in table A which tells which table will it get.

---

Ex:

Table A (Infos)

```
 InfoID | Type
```

Table B (Student)

```
 StudentID | Name | Course |
```

Table C (Employees)

```
 EmployeeID | Name | Company |
```

---

If type = 1 then get info in Table B(student)

```
InfoID | StudentID | Name | Course
```

Else get info in Table C(Employees)

```
InfoID | EmployeeID| Name | Company
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt. And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: @jarlh its okay now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
SELECT my_columns 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.InfoID = B.InfoID and A.type=1
LEFT JOIN C ON A.InfoID = C.InfoID and A.type <> 1
```

And for the columns you can use CASE / WHEN like that :

```
SELECT A.InfoId, 
MAX(CASE A.type = 1 THEN B.StudentID ELSE C.EmployeeID END) AS 'Employee/Student Id'
MAX(CASE A.type = 1 THEN B.Name ELSE C.Name END) AS 'Name'
MAX(CASE A.type = 1 THEN B.Course ELSE C.Company END) AS 'Company/Course'
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.InfoID = B.InfoID and A.type=1
LEFT JOIN C ON A.InfoID = C.InfoID and A.type <> 1
GROUP BY A.InfoID
```